# What is the name for the string between square bracket in C#?

Tags: c#

I have seen examples as following:

```
[Serializable]
public class TestFailedException : Exception { do stuff;}
```

Can anyone tell me the official terminology for this "[Serializable]"? Is it some kind of indexing attribute?

Thanks

Comment: ["Attribute"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Just FYI, you could have [Googled this](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+bracket) and gotten a myriad of answers to your question.

Comment: @jsve, thanks, I tried Googling, did not find much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terminology for these are [`attributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libraryaa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Attributes add some meta-data to code. They themselves do not execute, not in conventional way. They add some extra information about a method or class. When such a decorated method (or class) is called buy a different part of the code, that code can query the meta-data and perform some action accordingly.

You can use reflection to query the attributes on a method (or class). See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3).

In your particular example, the [[Serializable]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute tells CLR that given an instance of this class, the value of fields within that object can be *serialized*, i.e. can be sent over network, or can be written to disk. In this perspective, the [Serializable] attribute does not in any way adds that functionality, or helps in the process of *serialization*, just that it carries a meta-data that CLR should allow serialization.

Answer (score 2):

It's an `Attribute`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx

I've also heard people refer to them as `Annotations` but this is more of a `Java` term.